# How can I get the selected object of a drowpdown list using Thymeleaf?

Tags: jsp, thymeleaf

I have a dropdown list and a table, in the dropdown should all objects with the category "software" be listed(which works fine) and in the table all objects with the category "hardware" should be listed. But my goal is, if the software is incompatible with a hardware then this hardware should be disabled (grey).

So I'm trying to get access to the the "incompatible" list, so I can check if the hardware is compatible with the selected software from the dropdown. But I just couldn't find a solution to get the selected software.

here's my .html:

```
<select th:field="*{objects}" >
        <option th:each="software : ${objects}" 
            th:if="${software.category} == software" 
            th:value="${software.id}"
            th:text="${software.name}">
        </option>
    </select>

    <table class="table">
        <tr th:each="hardware: ${objects}"
            th:if="${hardware.category} == hardware"
            th:class="${#lists.contains([selectedSoftware].getIncompatible(), hardware)} ? disable : normal">
            <td th:text="${hardware.id}"></td>
            <td th:text="${hardware.name}"></td>
            <td th:text="${hardware.category}"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `thymeleaf` is server-side engine. In other words, `thymeleaf` has no idea about what the client is currently doing in the page **unless the user submits a form.** I'm assuming that you are submitting form since you have used `th:field`.

You are not using `th:field` correctly. Here, you are binding the selected value to the whole array of objects. The attribute `th:field` should point to a field within the `th:object` (a.k.a. Command) used in the your `<form>`. [For example](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#dropdownlist-selectors) and below:

```
<select th:field="*{selectedSoftwareId}" >
```

If you are looking for client-side solution, then you need to use Ajax and JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you for your respond, it's much clearer to me now :) So there's no way to refresh just the hardware table without submitting the form?

Comment: Using thymeleaf no, but using Ajax yes. You can find several examples  on the web. Please don't forget to accept the answer if you are satisfied with the answer.